# How to boost call recording volume level or open recorded file to adjust sounds

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I need to know how to boost call recording volume level
I am seeing this option on this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bazmo.TCR

Is anybody know some things about ?
i dont want it already tried!

```
       recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
   recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
   recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

Or how to open(extract) media file and Amplitude(increase sound volume level) voice then save out put to new media file.I saw some things on https://code.google.com/p/musicg
but dont know how to use...

And other question is there any method to reduce or adjust the microphone sound?

The last question how to add all android media recorder source(all sources the android device need to record sound) to my project?

Comment: Hi guys can anybody help me how to use audio compressor ?according this site sae.edu/reference_material/audio/pages/Compression.htm#comp i need open an output sound and use an audio compressor to adjust sounds thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To increase the call recording volume use AudioManager as follows:

int deviceCallVol;
AudioManager audioManager;

Start Recording:

```
     audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//get the current volume set
deviceCallVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
//set volume to maximum
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL), 0);

   recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
   recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
   recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

Stop Recording:

//revert volume to initial state

```
 audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, deviceCallVol, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks mate,i will try!but VOICE_CALL not working on many device and my device too (s2 kitkat ) should use MIC , downlink or uplink but MIC working on all!this is no problem already added option for change it!i need to amplitude the receiver voice not my voice!
 
also this is not the android maximum voice call volume that user can set manually??or this maximum volume is more than that?

Comment: It's the maximum volume. You can still use MiC audio source to record. Try it out with and without the code

Comment: Thanks I tried but no different between I manually set the voice call to maximum with codes set that to maximum both of them is same!
i need to extract the out put record media file and change the sounds increase sounds volume

Comment: Hi guys can anybody help me how to use audio compressor ?according this site
http://www.sae.edu/reference_material/audio/pages/Compression.htm#comp
i need open a output sound and use a audio compressor to adjust sounds thanks.